# Need help with xargs and substitution

Tags: linux, find, xargs

I got some command below, and I need to use the parameters passed inside of my `xargs` command to my `echo` command but I cant seem to get it right? If I try:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -wholename "$1" | xargs -I{} echo -e "<h2>Filename: {}</h2>\n<pre> `cat *`\n</pre>\n<br>
Word Count $(wc -w {})";
```

As you can see the `wc -w {}` wouldnt work inside of my `xargs` command it does treats it as a literal. And if I try:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -wholename "$1" | xargs -I{} echo -e "<h2>Filename: {}</h2>\n<pre> `cat *`\n</pre>\n<br>
Word Count $(wc -w ${})";
```

It gives me `${}` as an error message... I know it's probably because of the parsing, but I have no idea how to fix it, can someone help me?

Comment: Should `\`cat *\`` print the content of the corresponding file?

Comment: Never use `-wholename` since it is 100% non-portable.

Answer (score 2):

Write another simple script to produce the output you want, and run it from `find` with `-exec`, no need for `xargs`.  For example:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -wholename "$1" -exec /path/to/myscript.sh {} +
```

myscript.sh:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

for i in "$@"; do
  printf "<h2>Filename: %s</h2>\n<pre>" "$i"
  cat *
  printf "\n<pre>\n<br>Word Count %s\n" "$(wc -w "$i")"
done
```

Save this and make it executable, by running `chmod +x myscript.sh`.

I don't know why you'd want to run `cat *` (i.e. cat all files in the current directory) for every file found but that's what you asked for.  Are you sure you didn't want the contents of each file instead?  Use `cat "$i"` instead of `cat *`.

Alternatively, you can do it without an extra script by using `-exec sh -c ...` instead:

```bsh
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -wholename "$1" \
  -exec sh -c 'for i in "$@"; do
          printf "<h2>Filename: %s</h2>\n<pre>" "$i";
          cat "$i";
          printf "\n<pre>\n<br>Word Count %s\n" "$(wc -w "$i")";
        done' find-sh {} +
```

(extra newlines added to improve readability. the script works the same with or without them.)

BTW, if you need to exec a script that uses bash-only features, use `-exec bash -c ...` instead of `-exec sh -c ...`.

Comment: And my guess is OP meant `wc -w <"$i"` to only print the number of words without filename. You could also replace `-wholename` with the more portable `-path`.

Comment: yep, probably.   I don't want to make that assumption, though.  It probably makes more sense as a < redirection, but it's valid either way.

Comment: Doesnt $i print out the command line arguements on the terminal, and also is there a way we can do it without the for loop??

Comment: 1. what? why would using $i do that? a variable is only printed if you have code to do so, like `echo "$i"` or `printf "$i"`.  2.  you could do it without a for loop, but it's not a good idea.  The find would have to run the `sh -c ...` once for every filename it finds.  The for loop is so that the `sh -c ...` script is executed only once with multiple filenames arguments.  This is **much** faster, the script itself is trivial and takes very little time to execute, but the startup time and other overhead of actually forking the sh interpreter to run the script is many times greater.

Comment: if there's only a few filenames, it makes only a small difference.  but if there are hundreds or thousands, it's the difference between running it once and running it hundreds or thousands of times.  this could be the difference between taking seconds to execute vs taking minutes or even hours.